# Github workflow: invalid refspec

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a github workflow step to create an automated pull request against the `shuklsh-test-2` branch if one merges a pull request against `shuklsh-test-1`. Here is my job code:

```
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.AUTO_COMMIT_BOT_PAT }}
      - name: Create automated PR
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true && ${{ github.base_ref == 'shuklsh-test-1' }}
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.AUTO_COMMIT_BOT_PAT }}
          title: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
          body: ${{ github.event.pull_request.body }}
          base: shuklsh-test-2
          branch: ${{ github.base_ref }}
          labels: Automated PR
```

I am running the workflow in the context of branch `shuklsh-test-1`. The workflow `FAILS` at this step with the following error.

```
invalid refspec ':refs/remotes/origin'
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Please include the `on` section of your workflow in your question.

Comment: `actions/checkout` doesn't fetch all the branches, by default. It only fetches the default branch. See `ref` and `fetch-depth` under its [Usage](https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage) section for more details. You need to configure checkout's `with: fetch-depth: 0` to fetch all the branches. Apart from that, you start to use its `@v3` to avoid deprecation warnings for NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

The message appears on line 483, if you take time to squint a bit and understand the command on line 482, it says: `git fetch origin :refs/remotes/origin`, which is, as the error message suggests, invalid.

There probably is some value (the branch name ?) that isn't set correctly, and isn't substituted in that command (hence the empty string before the `:` and after the final `/`).

Check how your script receives the name of the branch (or tag or ref) to fetch.